# VS2017 - devenv.exe - Unknown Hard Error

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017

One of our developers is experiencing a system Warning popup when he tries to launch a solution in VS2017. all was working well before today

"devenv.exe - System Warning
Unknown Hard Error"

VS shuts down, whether he presses ok or not and  MSBuilds.exe are left in task manager

We tried:
 - repairing VS2017
 - un-install-restart-reinstall VS2017

Answer (score 2):

Had to remove all .NET components from the machine and re-install em - got it working. Very close to rebuilding the PC